# Losing RTTI info after returning from a function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, rtti, dynamic-cast

Given a class and subclass:

```
class Event {...}
class Note : public Event {...}
```

A Note is Cloned and stored in a pointer within a function f(). The type-information is preserved in the pointer and can be recovered by dynamic_cast:

```
void f()
{
   pEvent = pNote->Clone();    // create a clone of a Note
   ASSERT(dynamic_cast<Note*>(pEvent));   // check the pointer, here it works
}
```

Now, after returning from f() the type-information is lost:

```
f();
ASSERT(dynamic_cast<Note*>(pEvent));   // -> "Access violation - no RTTI-data"
```

The VS-debugger shows a valid pointer-value (unchanged), but not the derived class,
other than while beeing in the `f()`-scope.

How can the RTTI-info for a pointer be lost when returning from a function?

Comment: Are you sure `pEvent` is the same global variable in both cases and the name is not shadowed within `f`?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `pEvent`, the definition of `Event` and the _real_ code for `f()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a destructor accidently doing harm to the pointer. After removing this error, the RTTI works as expected.